# If I log on facebook on Chrome am I trackable when I use Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, user-tracking

I rarely use Facebook and rarely use Chrome. I would like to limit the tracking I am subject to, so I think it would be good to log on Facebook on Chrome and use only Chrome to use Facebook.

Does this separation of my use of Facebook save me from tracking when I use other browsers such as Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Go one step further and use a "portable" version of the browser you want to use as your "Facebook" browser. That ensures that you are not co-mingling your web files in the same directories, but allows that browser to collect cookies and internet files that makes it easier to use Facebook (if you want that).

The other thing to mention is to not log in to your Google account if you use Chrome. That connects your activities across browsers.

Comment: You mean that I should log in to my Google account only on one browser, do I get it right?

Comment: Chrome allows you to log into your google account from the browser app itself. Firefox has a similar ability to log into your Firefox sync account. That's what I mean.